# In Windows avoid nano triggering overwrite mode on cmd line

Tags: windows, command-line, nano

In Windows 8 I have installed `nano`, because it's my preferred command line text editor.

When I use it, it works normally, just as it would on any Linux distribution:

```
C:\>nano file.c
```

However, when I return to the `cmd` prompt overwrite mode is always enabled as if I had pressed the `insert` key. This is highly annoying because I'm frequently going back and forth between `nano` and the `cmd` prompt.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please report a bug to the authors of nano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
nano %1
echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{INSERT}" > Ins.vbs
cscript //B Ins.vbs
del Ins.vbs
```

Save the above as a batch file and call with the file name you want to edit.

Comment: That seems to fix the following command-line command, but then the one after that reverts to overwrite mode again. At least that's the case for me on Windows 7. On closer look, looking in the command window "Properties" menu, "Options" tab, nano somehow clears both "QuickEdit Mode" and "Insert Mode".

Comment: I assume a call to [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would solve it. I don't know how to script that with VBS though.